# iphone - Difference between [[self tabBarController] navigationController] and self.navigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that has a tabbarcontroller and for one tab I use a navigationcontroller.

Can someone tell me what the difference between `[[self tabBarController] navigationController]` and `self.navigationController` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[self tabBarController] navigationController]` will get the navigationController that the tabBarController is inside.

`self.navigationController` gets the navigationController that `self` is inside.

These properties will return `nil` if the respective instances are not part of a navigationController's stack (if they aren't in a navigationController)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `[[self tabBarController] navigationController]` is the current navigation controller of the selected tab. And `self.navigationController` is the navigation controller of the current class.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW44

The navigationController property returns a navigation controller if the the controller the property is asked from is in the navigation controller's stack.

Your tab bar controller is not part of a navigation controller of the tab bar which should be nil in your case.